# Auto formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, formatting

I am working on a problem in Excel. I'm responsible for tracking the movements in a nursing home.

What I need in an Excel spreadsheet is to keep track of the amount of days a person is in rehab. They have a maximum of 100 days per year, and I'd like to have something that automatically highlights a person after 25, 50 and 75 days (yellow, orange and red respectively).

I'd like to be alerted when the person reaches 25, 50 & 75 days.

Can this be done in excel? What should I try?

Comment: you can use conditional formatting, for example, either format the value 25 to green or anything between 25 to 49 to green.

Comment: It's just that a person who joins the program will be logged into the system with a date. After exactly 25 days, I want his record to be shown in green in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is the way to go for this.

You'd probably start with a formula on the worksheet like...

```
=IF([EndDate]="",DATEDIF([StartDate],TODAY(),"D"),DATEDIF([StartDate],[EndDate],"D"))
```

Essentially, if the end date is blank (i.e. the person hasn't left), then look at the difference between the start date and today's date in days (the "D"). If there is an end date then compare the start date with the end date (again in days).

Then you'd just do conditional formatting based on those values and highlight based on what you need.  Just be careful with the ordering of the 'conditions' though, or you may end up highlighting things the same colour rather than distinguishing them as you want.

[image]

There's a few assumptions made here - that a person doesn't have breaks in their stay and that their stay includes weekends/public holidays as well, but that should get you started I think.